# HTML Select List - how to have a watermark with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, this is somewhat driving me nuts.  I have a basic HTML page with a drop down:

```
<select id="someDropDown" class="watermarked">
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <option>Item 1</option>
   <option>Item 2</option>
</select>
```

Using this jQuery plugin, it says I can watermark a select list:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TinyWatermark

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.watermarked').watermark('watermark', 'derp');
});
```

with this css style:

```
.watermark 
{
    color: #999;
}
```

When I do this, the dropdown no longer drops, but it is watermarked...what am I doing wrong here?

btw- this is broken in chrome, but works in IE9 only if I double click the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that with a select. If you look at the demo, it's all for text input fields. That's usually how placeholder text things work.

Try this, though. It disables the "Please Select" item so when you open the list, it is gray and you can't select it again. This does not change the color normally though.

```
<select id="someDropDown" class="watermarked">
   <option disabled selected>Please Select</option>
   <option>Item 1</option>
   <option>Item 2</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery solution**

Make sure the Please Select option has the attributes `disabled selected` and the entire select has the `gray` class. This will style the dropdown box as you see it on the page to have a gray font color. The jQuery code will iterate over the non-disabled options and make them black. Then, when the selection changes, it will remove the `gray` class making the dropdown box black (default) as well.

**CSS**

```
.gray {
    color:#ccc;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="someDropDown" class="watermarked gray">
   <option disabled selected>Please Select</option>
   <option>Item 1</option>
   <option>Item 2</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#someDropDown option:not([disabled])").css("color", "#000");
$("#someDropDown").change(function() {
    $(this).css('gray');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/izacog)

Comment: Yeah I already have that, not what I'm looking for.  Is there a way to swap from a text box to a drop down?

Comment: You just want the text to be gray until I chose an item, right?

Comment: Yes, in all browsers.  The above solution does not work in chrome but it does work in IE.