# To check if an option has been added to dropdown using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown list to which an option is added.

```
var Option = "<option disabled=\"true\" selected=\"selected\" style=\"display: none;\">" + Choose the following + "</option>";
$dropdown.prepend(Option );
```

My issue is how do i check if the option is already present in the dropdown and if its not present then only add it to the dropdown.
I am fairly new to Jquery, please help.

Also can watermarks be added to a dropdown in JQuery.

Comment: This can be written much nicer:
`$('<option/>',{ "disabled":true, "selected":"selected", "style":"display: none;"}).text("Choose the following").prependTo($dropdown);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
if($dropdown.find('option:contains("Choose the following")').length > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to be able to distinguish each option based on one of it's attribute in your case let's say it's value.

```
if ($("#yourSelect option[value='yourValue']").length == 0) {
   // Add
}
else {
   // Already present don't add.
}
```

Also you don't need to declare your option like that, just use single quotes instead of double.

```
var Option = "<option disabled='true' selected='selected' style='display: none;'>" + "Choose the following" + "</option>";
```

And as far as adding watermarks is concerned [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11458931/903324).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(function(){     
       alert($('#DropDownID option').length);
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qcd3b/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like checking the options length and if length is 0 then prepend the option:

```
if($dropdown.find('option').length < 0){
    $dropdown.prepend(Option );
}
```